# Qt QScrollArea leftover graphic artifacts when scrolling with TranslucentBackground flag

Tags: c++, qt

I get graphic artifacts when scrolling a qscrollarea that is not a seperate window and both the scroll area and the target widget's TranslucentBackground flag is set to true. The problem doesn't happen when the scrollarea is opened as a seperate window with null parent or Qt::Window flag.

- Was this behavior intended or is this a bug?
- If it is a bug, is
  there a fix you know of?

I've tried many other window flags but all the ones that don't open a separate window have the same issue.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QScrollerProperties>
#include <QScroller>
#include <QTouchDevice>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *mainWindow = new QWidget;

    QHBoxLayout *buttonsLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    QWidget *buttonsWidget = new QWidget();
    buttonsWidget->setLayout(buttonsLayout);
    buttonsWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    buttonsWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Button " + QString::number(i), buttonsWidget);
        buttonsLayout->addWidget(button);

    }
    QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(mainWindow);
    scrollArea->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    scrollArea->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scrollArea->setFixedHeight(100);
    scrollArea->setWidget(buttonsWidget);
    scrollArea->setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

    mainWindow->show();
    scrollArea->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Example artifact when, compiled with Qt5.12.1 open source version, ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. A *workaround* might be to call `update()` on the widget whenever there's a scroll event.